# 3D Button effect with CSS Drop-shadow and transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, box-shadow

I'm trying to create set of 3d button effects with css-drop shadow and css transitions. I got everything working, it looks good, but when the button is clicked, the shadow moves towards to button, and I want it to stay in one place, and only for the button to move.

here's a codepen demo how it looks now.

```
`http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/ZYRRar`
```

I tried changing the timing on the transition, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem here

```
box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 1px 0px #1976D2,
                2px 1px 0px #1976D2,1px 2px 0px #1976D2;
```

change to this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 0px 0px #1976D2,
                0px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 0px 0px #1976D2;
```

```css
button {
 /*  */
 padding:35px;
 margin: 0;
 width:350px;
 
 /* Font Styling */
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFF;
 }
 
button:active {
 outline:none;
 }

.rightBottom {

 transition: margin-top 0.3s ease, 
    margin-left 0.3s ease, 
    box-shadow 0.3s ease;
 
 background:#03A9F4;
 border: solid 1px #1976D2;

   box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 1px 0px #1976D2,
      2px 1px 0px #1976D2,1px 2px 0px #1976D2,
      3px 2px 0px #1976D2,2px 3px 0px #1976D2,
      4px 3px 0px #1976D2,3px 4px 0px #1976D2,
      5px 4px 0px #1976D2,4px 5px 0px #1976D2,
      6px 5px 0px #1976D2,5px 6px 0px #1976D2,
      7px 6px 0px #1976D2,6px 7px 0px #1976D2,
      8px 7px 0px #1976D2,7px 8px 0px #1976D2,
      9px 8px 0px #1976D2,8px 9px 0px #1976D2;
 }
 
.rightBottom:active{

 transition: margin-top 0.3s ease, 
    margin-left 0.3s ease, 
    box-shadow 0.3s ease;

    margin-left:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 0px 0px #1976D2,
      0px 0px 0px #1976D2,0px 0px 0px #1976D2;
   
}
```

```html
<button class="rightBottom">I am a Button!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) but is there a way to still leave a 2px shadow on :active? or that's what masses it up

Comment: You are welcome :) and I like this button it is great. The problem was that you placed shadow with margin arguments. I am not sure how to add shadow but if such thing will work probably it will be outside of .rightBottom:active.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Anyways, I changed all the styles so they don't have shadows after pushed down. Thanks again :)

Comment: You are welcome :) If you can please share your final result I am very interested in it.

Comment: Sure, here they are [link](http://andornagy.com/examples/3d-button-css-dropshadow/)

Comment: Awesome:) your website has 1 more visitor from now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS below.
CSS

```
.down {
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease ;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
    transition: margin-top 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;

    background:#1abc9c;
    border: solid 1px #16a085;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #16a085;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #16a085;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px #16a085;
}
.down:active{
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: margin-top 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;

    margin-top:9px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #16a085;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #16a085;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #16a085;
}
```

Comment: Hi. All posts in StackOverflow---questions and answers---should be in English. It would be great if you can take time to translate and edit your post in English.